# Как работает функция env() в css. не только на iphone, но и в браузерах ПК и телефонах Android

Tags: html, css

Я пытался понять эту функцию и прочитал много статей о ней, но по поводу этой функции возникли некоторые вопросы․

1.Является ли функция `env()` только для iPhone?

2.Если нет, то в каком случае вам следует использовать функцию `env()` в случае компьютерного браузера?

3.Если мы можем указать `content="viewport-fit=contain"` или `content="viewport-fit=auto"` в метатеге, то зачем использовать `content="viewport-fit=cover"` и вместе с ним `env()` функция.?

Comment: На практике `viewport-fit=cover` может использоваться в мобильных приложениях на основе полноэкранного браузера (webview), чтобы позиционировать элементы от самой верхней кромки экрана, а не внутри "безопасной" зоны. Таким образом веб-интерфейс может заползать под системные значки состояния в верхней части экрана и под чёлку айфона. Обычно такие приложения выглядят более "нативно".

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ.  а эти 4 переменные только для Iphon-ов, или они будут активни на браузерах андроид?

Comment: и последни.... эти переменые будут активни в нотбуках и настолних компютерах?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env() — смотрите иллюстрации и таблицу совместимости с браузерами.

Comment: спасибо вам болшое.....